# How to speed up the package loading in R (in Shiny app)

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, r-highcharter

I use `highchart` `js` library for my dynamic plotting in R. I observed that it takes significant time just to get it loaded onto my R workplace. As per below timing it takes hopping 8s just to load

```
> system.time(library(highcharter))
Highcharts (www.highcharts.com) is a Highsoft software product which is
not free for commercial and Governmental use
   user  system elapsed 
  0.718   0.155   8.191
```

I am using this package in my `Shiny` app. Is there any way to speed up this loading? Almost all packages takes 1-2 seconds to load.

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For me it took less than 1 second.

```
> system.time(library(highcharter))
Highcharts (www.highcharts.com) is a Highsoft software product which is
not free for commercial and Governmental use
   user  system elapsed 
   0.07    0.00    0.06
```

R and highcharter Version

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)
highcharter_0.7.0
```

Comment: I guess it already imported by you and/or some other package

Comment: I restarted my machine and load highcharter library. It took 1.6 seconds

Comment: This is interesting. Not sure if this due to use of Windows as OS. I am using Ubuntu and also tested in Mac, both take significant amount of time to load the package.

Comment: Try the development version from Github. In the latest version plugins are not loaded by default. It should speed up loading the package

Comment: Yes, this development version is much quick to load. Thanks for letting us know. I am now able to load this in less than 1s. But still it takes 0.883s contrary to 0.06 which you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (it's just a blind shot) it is because the Highcharts library is huge. Look at all the Highcharts, Highstock, Highmaps cores and all additional modules: http://code.highcharts.com/

Each core contains tens or hundreds of thousands lines of JavaScript code. When you add all additional modules, e.g. `highcharts-more.js`, `highcharts-3d` and more, you get even more. Highcharter wrapper contains most of the Highcharts features (almost all of them). Maybe that is why it's loading so long.

I am not R developer, so maybe there is a way to improve loading time. Just keep in mind that is may be caused by the size of the library itself.